# seeking a way to initialize dict in a more efficient way

Tags: python, dictionary

```
prior={}
conditionProb={}
Counts={}

for i in range(len(trainingData)):
    label=trainingLabels[i]
    prior[label]+=1
    datum=trainingData[i]
    for j in range(len(datum)):
        Counts[(i,j,label)]+=1
        if(datum[j]>0):
            conditionProb[(i,j,label)]+=1
```

when I run this code, it will report a key error because prior do not initialize first so the value is 0. I can initialize these 3 dict by loops but it seems put too many code to do the work. So I am seeking some other way to do this, e.g. override default method in dict? I am not familiar with python. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` to initialize keys to `0`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

prior = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
conditionProb = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
Counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for i, (label, data) in enumerate(zip(trainingLabels, trainingData)):
    prior[label] += 1
    for j,datum in enumerate(data):
        Counts[i, j, label] += 1
        if datum > 0:
            conditionProb[i, j, label] += 1
```

Comment: You can also just use use `defaultdict(int)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict from the collections module. You construct it passing the type of values in there, in this case an int, plus a default value if it's not set (default is 0). Do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(int)
my_dict['foo'] += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c['a'] += 2
>>> c
Counter({'a': 2})
```